# UIPopoverPresentationController showing as full-window popup

Tags: ios, swift

This question has been asked 3 times already pre Swift 4 I think and I'm having a similar problem.

My `UIPopoverPresentationController` is showing as full-window popup in portrait + landscape and adding `.None` does not fix the issue. I'm using an iPhone 6 as a simulator via xcode.

Here's what I have:

```
@objcMembers class ViewController: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "settingsPopoverSegue" {

        let buttonItemView = settingsButton.value(forKey: "view")
        let viewForSource = (buttonItemView as! UIView)
        popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewForSource

        let popoverViewController = segue.destination
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
    }
}

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {

        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }
}
```

I have the segue connected from a uibarbutton on Storyboard to the popoverViewController.

Updated code above - Alright, so I added a sourceView but the popover is still sliding up a full screen. I must still be missing something. Any idea?

Second update: Put it in an action from the settings barbutton and still the iphone shows full screen:

```
@IBAction func settingsTapped(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if segue.identifier == "settingsPopoverSegue" {

        let buttonItemView = settingsButton.value(forKey: "view")
        let viewForSource = (buttonItemView as! UIView)
        popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewForSource

        let popoverViewController = segue.destination
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give a source rect to open it. If you want to open it from specific point then give a source view.

```
 let buttonItemView = YourBarButtonItem.value(forKey: "view")
 et buttonItem = (buttonItemView as! UIView)
 popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = Your Rect
 popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = buttonItem
```

Comment: Id like to open it from a barbutton, so is it: popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
            popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up;

Comment: @bhealth Should have a non-nil `sourceView` or `barButtonItem` set before the presentation occurs.
`sourceRect` is optional.

Comment: Alright, so I added a sourceView but the popover is still sliding up a full screen. I must still be missing something. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps try adding the `preferredContentSize` property to `popoverViewController` with a rectangle that works for you?